# VS Code Python 'autocompletion' and 'go to definition' for GAE not working

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, go-to-definition

recently I've started to use VS Code instead of sublime text 3.

But I've got small issue, neither `Go To Definition` nor `Autocomplete` works.

When I try, for example, import json then, try to json. it keeps saying that it's "loading" [See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FLHE.png)

I have had simillar issues with Sublime text, but after all it found all the stuff.

I'm using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python and I've set all required variables.
Not sure if that's package issue or my config.

Probably it might be because project I'm in uses buildout. but I've set correct way too. Even added extra paths for buildout `.eggs` directory and `.parts` where appengine is located.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's jedi related issue. Make sure you have corresponding 'grammarx.x.txt' file in ~.vscode-insiders\extensions\donjayamanne.python-x.x.x\pythonFiles\preview\jedi\parser

I had the same issue after installing Python 3.6, so I just copied grammar3.5.txt to grammar3.6.txt in ~.vscode-insiders\extensions\donjayamanne.python-0.5.5\pythonFiles\preview\jedi\parser and my autocompletion started to work again.

Comment: I do have the file:
 ```ls ~/.vscode/extensions/donjayamanne.python-0.5.5/pythonFiles/preview/jedi/parser/
fast.py  grammar2.7.txt  grammar3.4.txt  grammar3.5.txt  __init__.py  pgen2  tokenize.py  token.py  tree.py  utils.py```

I believe the issue would be with indexing the files, because the project is pretty big.